# Custom display in CRUDified object

Tags: scala, lift

I have a an entity referencing another entity by MappedLongForeignKey.

I am using the CRUDify trait and have a problem.

```
Entity 1:
id
title (String)
validTo (Date)

Entity 2:
id
...
fk_entity_1 (mapped via MappedLongForeignKey)
```

In the listings generated by CRUDify for entity 2 I would like to include a column formatted as

```
fk_entity_1.title ( fk_entity_1.validTo )
```

I tried to create a function returning such a string and adding that fn to fieldsForDisplay, but it seems fieldsForDisplay requires mapped fields.

Is this possible to accomplish?

*** Edit ***
What I am trying to accomplish is (using the built in functionality of CRUDify for listings) produce listings as:

```
{Entity 2 fields}   "Entity 1"
 ...                Title_X (2001-01-01)
 ...                Title_Y (2011-02-02)
```

If worse comes to worst, I can roll my own listings, but I really like the CRUDify functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you're trying to accomplish, but maybe you could override the asHtml method of the fields instead?